# knitr LaTeX single quotes not typesetting correctly

Tags: latex, knitr

ers,

Our lab is having trouble getting R code containing single quotes to typeset correctly in LaTeX. The documents compile fine without errors, but R code that is encased by single quotes is not typeset, so the R code is not presented correctly.

The problem persists independent of the tools used to compile the .Rnw to pdf. So far we have tried compiling in RStudio, and on the CLI using knit() with calls to pdflatex, and using knit2pdf().

We have produced a working example of our problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{upquote} %Using this pkg does not fix single quotes problem
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} %Problem persists with or without Computer Modern
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage{inconsolata} %Problem persists with or without inconsolata
\usepackage[auth-sc]{authblk}
%
\title{Some title \\ \vspace{3 mm}
{\large \textit{Supplemental Methods To:}\\ 
\normalsize "Even bigger title"}}

\begin{document}

<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
# this is equivalent to \SweaveOpts{...}
opts_chunk$set(fig.path='figure/minimal-', fig.align='center', fig.show='hold')
options(replace.assign=TRUE,width=90)
#require(highlight) # Problem persists with or without highlight
@

\maketitle

\section{Some Section}
In R, characters can be entered with double quotes or single quotes. The single quote is the apostrophe key next to ENTER on an American keyboard.\\
This R code with characters contained by single quotes does not render correctly in \LaTeX{}. But characters in double quotes do render correctly.
<<raw_nums>>=
Vector1<-c('A','B','C') # This line not typeset correctly; the quotes are missing in the pdf
Vector1
Vector2<-c("A","B","C") # Typeset correctly
Vector2
@

<<sessionInfo>>=
sessionInfo()
@

\end{document}
```

One workaround is always use double quotes, but many of us use single quotes by convention. We wondered if anyone else had noticed this issue, and if they found a solution ?

Thanks, Philip A.

R version: 3.2.1
knitR version: 1.10.5
LaTeX 2e
Ubuntu Precise 64bit

Comment: When I save your "minimal" example, it compiles just fine. I guess there's something wrong with your configuration (locale, file encoding). How exactly do you compile the PDF? The "Compile to PDF" button in RStudio, `knit2pdf()`, `knit()` and then manually calling `pdflatex`, ...?

Comment: The .Rnw compiles fine to pdf, but on our system the R code `Vector1<-c('A','B','C')` does not typeset correctly. In the PDF, all the single quotes are missing, so the R code is presented improperly in the PDF. The corresponding line in the .tex file: `\hlstd{Vector1}\hlkwb{<-}\hlkwd{c}\hlstd{(}\hlstr{'A'}\hlstd{,}\hlstr{'B'}\hlstd{,}\hlstr{'C'}\hlstd{)} \hlcom{# This line not typeset correctly; the quotes are missing in the pdf}` In your compiled pdf, are the single quotes typeset correctly on the offending line in the R chunk ? @user2706569

Comment: Exactly the line you posted is contained in the TEX file generated here and this line renders just fine in the final PDF (including the single quotes!). That's why I guess this is not a directly `knitr` related issue but has some other causes like to tool you use to compile or encodings. Maybe [TEX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) is more suitable for you question, when you condense it to just `'` not being rendered.